# How do I crop all locations of image through a np.array of points within python?

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, numpy-ndarray

I'm setting up a for loop to crop different parts of an image from my np.array of 22. How do I set up the for loop correctly and so it runs fast?

I know I need an empty array to put the crops in.

```
crop_array = np.empty([])



#test with y1,y2,x1,x2 points 
rect = np.array([[137,166,14,80],[174,204,14,80],[214,244,14,80], 
[252,282,14,80],[290,320,14,80],[328,358,14,80],[366,396,14,80], 
[402,432,14,80],[65,94,161,227],[102,131,199,265],[139,168,234,300], 
[179,208,270,336],[217,246,306,372],[254,283,344,410],[293,322,381,447],
[65,94,235,301],[102,131,273,339],[139,168,308,374],[179,208,344,410], 
[217,246,380,446],[254,283,418,478]])

#this is one point and works
crop0 = small2gray[137:166,14:80].copy()
```

Answer (score 0):

Given the np.array given for rect.

```
#y1,y2,x1,x2 points within each list
rect = np.array([[137,166,14,80],[174,204,14,80],[214,244,14,80], 
[252,282,14,80],[290,320,14,80],[328,358,14,80],[366,396,14,80], 
[402,432,14,80],[65,94,161,227],[102,131,199,265],[139,168,234,300], 
[179,208,270,336],[217,246,306,372],[254,283,344,410],[293,322,381,447],
[65,94,235,301],[102,131,273,339],[139,168,308,374],[179,208,344,410], 
[217,246,380,446],[254,283,418,478]])

#For loop to contents of list that are nested
for (a,b,c,d) in rect:
   #Crop ROI Location
   crop_empty = smallgray[a:b,c:d].copy()
   crop = small2gray[a:b,c:d].copy
```

Website explaining nested lists.
https://cognitiveclass.ai/blog/nested-lists-multidimensional-numpy-arrays/

Here is a video of explanation to.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rUDdguWk-QQ